# Changing default make command

Tags: kubuntu, make

I'm taking the course of HarvardX: CS50x Introduction to Computer Science. Normally for doing this course you have to use a virtual machine for running a Fedora system called the cs50 appliance, with all the things made easy, but I already use Kubuntu so I downloaded clang and the cs50 library and I want to change the default options of `make` to include the library and stop when there are errors in the c program that I try to compile. In the appliance the make command does: `clang -ggdb3 -00 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror  -argv-2.c -lcs50 -lm -o argv-2`. It would be nice if you can explain what should be included and why. When I compile a .c file using make, it doesn't load the cs50 library and I get: undefined function ...

I tried writing `$ nano ~/.bashrc`. Then went to the end of the file and put

```
 #CS50 alias for C compiling:
 alias makec='gcc -ggdb3 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -argv-2.c -lcs50 -lm -o -argv-2'
```

Then `$ source .bashrc`

When I do `$ makec hello` now it says:

```
gcc: error: hello: No such file or directory
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-argv-2.c’
```

Comment: can you clarify your question ? also this question is quite broad and it is unclear how this relates to ubuntu.

Comment: There are no "default" options for `make`. It does whatever you tell it do in your `Makefile`. Can you post the exact errors you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export CC=gcc
export CFLAGS="-ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror"
export LDLIBS="-lcs50 -lm"
```

-ggdb

```
       Produce debugging information for use by GDB.  This means
       to use the most expressive format available (DWARF 2,
       stabs, or the native format if neither of those are
       supported), including GDB extensions if at all possible.
```

-ggdblevel

```
       Request debugging information and also use level to specify
       how much information.  The default level is 2.

       Level 3 includes extra information, such as all the macro
       definitions present in the program.  Some debuggers support
       macro expansion when you use -g3.
```

-O0

```
       Reduce compilation time and make debugging produce the
       expected results.  This is the default. (Is a optimization option)
```

-Wall

```
       Turns on all optional warnings which are desirable for
       normal code.  At present this is -Wcomment, -Wtrigraphs,
       -Wmultichar and a warning about integer promotion causing a
       change of sign in "#if" expressions.  Note that many of the
       preprocessor's warnings are on by default and have no
       options to control them.
```

-Werror

```
       Make all warnings into hard errors.  Source code which
       triggers warnings will be rejected.
```

-lm

```
       possibly loads a math library.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is related to the programs gcc and ld.
Environment variables C_INCLUDE_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are places to search for headers and libraries respectively. The gcc options -l and -L are of use, it's usual to declare something like

LIBRARIES= -lcs

LIBDIR=-L/usr/local/lib

Then use these make-variables in the commands run by each rule. 
If you installed these libraries using apt-get there may be package config data available see command pkg-config

Comment: I don't know what the environment variables are. But anyway I'm able to compile .c source code doing `gcc -ggdb3 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror hello.c -lcs50 -lm -o hello` and I want to do the same doing `make hello.c`.

Comment: Speak to your department's network admin to get an understanding of the basics like environmet variables. Buy the wrox book begining linux progra

Comment: ... programming. There's a wealth of knowledge in that. Commands like apropos, man and info will also help

Answer (score 0):

*I do not think this is solving your problem, but to answer the question as stated:*

There are some ways to set default options for `make`:

- Using a shell alias, like

  ```
  alias make='make --foo=bar'
  ```

  in `~/.bashrc` or similar.
- Setting the environment variable `MAKEFLAGS` to contain default options.
- Using the environment variable `MAKEFLAGS` to add the default option `-e` (`--environment-overrides`), and define other variables relevant to the makefiles in `~/.bashrc`, to be picked up by `make`, prioritized over definitions in the `Makefile`

With each of this methods, all uses of `make` are affected, which is not really what you want here.

A better solution seems to be to not change the default options of `make`,
but to use a separate alias to run make interactively. The alias can set options for recursive invocations of `make`.

```
alias cs50make='make --foo=bar'
```

or

```
alias cs50make='MAKEFLAGS="..." make'
```

or even

```
alias cs50make='MAKEFLAGS="-e ..." VAR1="..." VAR2="..." make'
```

Regarding making `make` stop on errors: It should normally do that by default, but if it's somewhere set to not stop, you can use the option `-S` (`--no-keep-going`, `--stop`) to override.

Answer (score 0):

You 're make rule should read something like this,

hello : hello.c

```
gcc -ohello hello.c -g -lcs50 -lm
```

Now just type command

make hello